# How create flexible layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How to make a layout, so there are no empty places?
Take a look at the picture:

[image: look_pls]

maybe some angular plugin? or some idea how to do the layout?
Thanks!

```css
.wrap {
    display: block;
}

.test {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px; // one card should be 400px
    height: 160px; // one card should be 320px
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="test">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="test">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="test">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="test">
                        4
                    </div>
                    <div class="test">
                        5
                    </div>
                    <div class="test">
                        6
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try masonry https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: https://github.com/desandro/masonry

Answer (score 0):

Use css display : grid to achieve your matrix layout. Refer this code, to achieve your result.

Refer actual docs or https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example7/

```css
.box-wrapper {
        display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: [col1-start] 100px  [col2-start] 100px  [col3-start] 100px [col4-start] 100px [col4-end];
        grid-template-rows: [row1-start] auto [row2-start] auto [row2-end];
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: col1-start / col3-start;
        grid-row: row1-start ;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: col3-start ;
        grid-row: row1-start / row2-end;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: col1-start;
        grid-row: row2-start ;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: col2-start ;
        grid-row: row2-start ;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). There is some good exercices online like [this](https://flexboxfroggy.com/).
For your case, you can try something like this :

```
.wrap{
    display: flex;
}
.test-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="test-wrapper">
    <div class="test">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        5
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test" style="width: 400px; height: 320px;">
    2
</div>
<div class="test-wrapper">
    <div class="test">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        6
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    4
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is used for the cases when you want to align a row or column, not grid.

Comment: Flexbox works perfectly to create responsive and flexibles layouts, including grids.

Comment: if ofcourse you can do that with flexbox, but display grid is out just for making grids layout. And its recommended to use the latest thing that is available.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is  to use css grid.

Link for learning https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: it seems like a bad idea (
css grid do not cover height